# Annotated Android Class Hierarchy

Tags: android, hierarchy, class-diagram

For the life of me, I can't see the "big picture". Every time I think I learned something  about Android, a new class pops up in some sample/example code.

True, I can look it up in the (terse) [formal reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html), but I need something additional: A class hierarchy map, that can remind me of the various relationships between the classes. Something like [this](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/hierarchy_stable_image.htm).

Ideally, I would be able to print it on paper so that it's always in front of my eyes while learning Android.

Is there [such a diagram](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_frm/thread/19030f9ef2b6fff2/059cf14655f4caa0?tvc=1#059cf14655f4caa0) somewhere?

Comment: Awesome question! We only stumble around without the big picture.

Answer (score 2):

The hierarchy is not very deep. I think the best way to get acquainted might be to start with [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and then look at the "direct subclasses" and "indirect subclasses" section at the top.

The big divisions for `View` are

- `TextView` - including `EditText` and `Button`
- `ViewGroup` - just about every container

Within `ViewGroup` there are both `Layouts` and more complicated widgets like the `ListView` family.

Try answering some questions on Stackoverflow, even if you are new. You'll have to learn all sorts of classes that you wouldn't have used otherwise.

Once you dive into writing code and learn to love the documentation, you'll naturally acquire a mental map of the classes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am amazed that after so many years no one has come up with a class diagram yet. I may be the first one to create it...

Comment: Let me know if you complete it. An even better diagram for me would be one that shows which major features have come and gone in which API level, because that is something I find tedious to look up in the docs, even after a bit of experience doing so.

Answer (score 1):

In android studio, you can see the whole android inheritence tree from `Navigate`>`Type Hierarchy`. But as android is very complex, for beginners, it won't make that much of a sense.

Answer (score 1):

Still looking for the same thing. A full diagram(s) of the hierarchy.
Ideally, when typing a class name or a method, it draws a diagram with the full inheritance but unfortunately i didn't find that.

Today i found something that can really help each of us that looking for such diagram:

[http://landenlabs.com/android/classtree/classtree.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20101203032443/http://www.adakoda.com/adakoda/2010/01/20/ASPH_AW_REV1.pdf)

And also, the link proided by Ben doesn't work anymore so i found the diagram here but it shows the full View hierarchy ony:

[wayback machine view hierarchy PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20101203032443/http://www.adakoda.com/adakoda/2010/01/20/ASPH_AW_REV1.pdf)

Hope it helps.